# Unable to install fetch (sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-fetch*)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Guys,

I am trying to install the Fetch model on my machine but failed to do so due to following error:

```
roy@RoysMacUbuntu:~/ws/src/stockroom_bot$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-fetch*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-fetch*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ros-indigo-fetch*'
```

I also tried ros-kinetic-fetch* (because I am using ROS kinetic). Didn't work either:

```
roy@RoysMacUbuntu:~/ws/src/stockroom_bot$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-fetch*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-fetch*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ros-kinetic-fetch*'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ros-kinetic-fetch*'
```

I ran apt-get update already.

Any idea where the problem might be?

Many thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270581/unable-to-install-fetch-(sudo-apt-get-install-ros-indigo-fetch*)/) by [roy](https://answers.ros.org/users/31312/roy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: as of 2017-09-10 there is no (official) binary release of the Fetch Robotics packages for Ubuntu Xenial-ROS Kinetic, so the commands you show are expected to fail

---

> I am using ROS kinetic

and

> ```
> roy@RoysMacUbuntu:~/ws/src/stockroom_bot$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-fetch*
> ```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-fetch*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ros-indigo-fetch*'
```

This will never work as Indigo binaries (`.deb`s) are not available on OS where you can install Kinetic. I guess you are running Ubuntu Xenial, for which only ROS Kinetic has been released.

> ```
> roy@RoysMacUbuntu:~/ws/src/stockroom_bot$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-fetch*
> ```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-fetch*
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ros-kinetic-fetch'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ros-kinetic-fetch'
```

> I ran apt-get update already.
>
> Any idea where the problem might be?

And this can't work as the Fetch packages have not been released into Kinetic. See [status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=fetch](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=fetch) ([indigo status](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=fetch) for comparison) and the [wiki/fetch_maps](http://wiki.ros.org/fetch_maps) page (fi, this is just an example).

According to [fetchrobotics/fetch_ros#56](https://github.com/fetchrobotics/fetch_ros/issues/56), it should be possible to build the various packages from sources in a Catkin workspace on a Xenial-Kinetic install, but as always, you might encounter some issues.

Note that just `git clone`-ing the repositories into a Catkin workspace is *not enough*. See #q252478 for the general steps needed to build packages from source.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2